# Is it possible to link image to Word document?

Tags: metadata, image-upload

The question is about Sharepoint 2010.

Let's say I've got a library of images. Is it possible to embed these images into Word documents (or content types extending Word documents) stored in Sharepoint, so the information about the link between the document and the image is preserved?

If such feature exists, how is it possible later to, for example, query the document library for specific image usages, or query the document library for usages of images with specific tags, etc.